# webbrowser c++ buider how to prevent executing "mailto" when a link of this type is clicked

Tags: c++builder, twebbrowser

I use c++buider4 and TWebBrowser. How can I avoid "mailto" to be executed when this type of link is clicked? Actually, I dont want this link to be executed because when it's executed, it switch to mail application and open a new windows.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the `OnBeforeNavigate2` event to cancel the operation if the URL being requested starts with `mailto:`.